# Elements not being hidden after animation is complete

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, hide

I can't for the life of me figure out why this function I'm running isn't hiding the elements. When hovering over a list item I want two divs inside it to animate to a `49%` height and when the mouse leaves this list item they go back to `0` and get `display: none;` again. However they just stay at `display: block;` even though the statement in the callback function of the `animate` executes.

Here's what it looks like when they're animated to `49%`:

[image: animation complete image]

And here's when they go back to `0`:

[image: image of the error that occurrs]

The two `div` elements containing the images doesn't get hidden with the `.hide()` function in the callback for some reason.

This is the function that doesn't work:

```
$('#site-wrapper').on('mouseenter', '#images-list li', function() {

    $(this).children('div').show().stop().animate({height: '49%'}, 'fast');
}).on('mouseleave', '#images-list li', function() {

    $(this).children('div').stop().animate({height: 0}, 'fast', function() {
        $(this).children('div').hide();
    });
});
```

This solution works but it hides it straight away without the user being able to see the animation, which I don't want:

```
$('#site-wrapper').on('mouseenter', '#images-list li', function() {

    $(this).children('div').show().stop().animate({height: '49%'}, 'fast');
}).on('mouseleave', '#images-list li', function() {

    $(this).children('div').stop().animate({height: 0}, 'fast').hide();
});
```

What should I do to solve this rather stupid bug?

Comment: anywhere we can see this in action?

Comment: @darshanags Can't seem to get the fiddle to work unfortunately, working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs on [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) (emphasis mine)

> **Complete Function**
>
> If supplied, the complete callback function is fired once the
>   animation is complete. This can be useful for stringing different
>   animations together in sequence. The callback is not sent any
>   arguments, but **`this` is set to the DOM element being animated**.

So instead of

```javascript
...
.on('mouseleave', '#images-list li', function() {
    $(this).children('div').stop().animate({height: 0}, 'fast', function() {
        $(this).children('div').hide(); // Wrong line
    });
});
```

It should be

```javascript
...
.on('mouseleave', '#images-list li', function() {
    $(this).children('div').stop().animate({height: 0}, 'fast', function() {
        $(this).hide(); // Hide the same div that was animated
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this? It would be better to use a fiddle to demonstrate this:

```
$('#site-wrapper').on('mouseenter', '#images-list li', function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.children('div').show().stop().animate({height: '49%'}, 'fast');
}).on('mouseleave', '#images-list li', function() {
    $this.children('div').stop().animate({height: 0}, 'fast', function() {
        $this.children('div').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: It's an "isch" solution, it works if I leave a list item and don't go into another one before the animation is complete. But if I enter another list item quickly it doesn't animate in the new list item and the previous list item's divs remains visible.